# Spark2 Java Dataset Sql

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

Trying to run the JavaSparkSQLExample in Spark2. using spark-core_2.11-2.0.2 and spark-sql_2.11-2.0.2. There is a error: `The method createGlobalTempView(String) is undefined for the type Dataset<Row>.`

Actually the [latest API docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaPairRDD.html) do not have this method defined. [Also the programming Guide](https://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-nightly/spark-master-docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html) has this. Anyone has a clue on this.

Also how do we build the session - as you cant' run with: `.config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")`.

```
SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
```

Comment: Which Spark version do you use? `createGlobalTempView()` is available since 2.1.0

Comment: @ Anton Okolnychyi I am using spark-core_2.11-2.0.2 and spark-sql_2.11-2.0.2 looking at the latest [API Docs] [1]  [1]:http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html

Comment: Correct, the API docs are also for 2.0.2 since Spark 2.1 is not officially available. Did you find the example in the Spark sources? I cannot find `createGlobalTempView()` in the Spark SQL programming guide for release 2.0.2. If you are looking at the code in master, you see unreleased Spark 2.1.

Comment: Yes it is there in the programming guide also- it does not refer to any release version. Also the example does not refer to a version. https://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-nightly/spark-master-docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html

Answer (score 0):

- According to your comments, you are looking at the programming guide of a Spark nightly build. It is based on the master branch and contains code that is not released yet. Most likely, it will land in Spark 2.2.0. On the other hand, your artifacts and API docs are for the latest officially available Spark version - 2.0.2. `createGlobalTempView()` appeared only in 2.1 (which is coming soon but not available as well). Therefore, you cannot use `createGlobalTempView()` with Spark 2.0.2 (the version of your artifacts). To see what is available in Spark 2.0.2, refer to this [guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html).
- Every Spark application needs a [Master URL](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls). You can pass it as a parameter to `spark-submit` or directly set in code:

  `val spark = SparkSession.builder()
     .appName("App name")
     .master("local[4]")
     .getOrCreate()`

Comment: OK yes I am on 2.0.2 and I don't really care for the `createGlobalTempView` I just have mistaken got it. Incidentally The guide you have provided also refers to the same example code link (so its the same new code). I  commented it out this portion. Tried `.master("local[4]")` - **it worked**. I finally actually need to connect to Cassandra - how? In older version we use  SparkConf ` conf.setMaster("local[*]"); conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost");
        conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042");` What do we do now?  Thanks much,

Comment: You can set using ".config" in Spark 2. SparkSession.builder()
   .appName("App name")
   .master("local[4]")
   .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")
   .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
   .getOrCreate()